# Mercurial - Add project which is not within repository folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial

I am an inexperienced Mercurial user.  I am using VS2010 with Mercurial.  I had everything working nicely against a single repository, which contained a solution file and two projects nested within the 'parent' folder.  Whenever I changed a file then the commit process would detect the change etc, etc.

Then I added a third project.  I added this project in a new folder, where the new folder was a peer of the top-level folder containing the original solution file (with original 2 projects nested within).  Although the third project has been added to the solution file, it is not being recognised by Mercurial as 'belonging' to the solution in terms of source control.  Indeed, it is not showing as being under source control at all.

How do I add the third project to the same repository, even though it sits 'outside' the original folder which maps to the original Mercurial repository?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a different repository for each project. This is because when you do a commit in hg, the commit is for the entire hierarchy, not just the directory (and below) that you are in. For more details have a look at the *One last big conceptual difference* section of http://hginit.com/00.html

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot add anything that is not under the repository root. `hg add` will abort with `X not under root` message. Move your files into the repository, or move the repository so that all of your files are under the root (note that this will generate a lot of file moves, and you really shouldn't do that).

Answer (score 1):

I found the best way to manage multiple folders in one repo by just creating a symlink (mklink in windows). I usually work in Visual Studio, so I typically have a code library and a website directory, but they are not in the same parent folder.

You can create a symlink on windows like so:

```
mklink /J "Target Path" "Source Path"
```

So I would have a structure like so:

```
project root
- Code Library
- Solution File
- Web Folder (symlink from locally-hosted website folder)
```