# How to add subprojects to a main project in mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I'm new to mercurial and tortoise and I have some problems trying to understand how to work with sub-projects.

I have three folders called **UART**, **SPI** and **ADC**. These folders contain code to use the uart, spi and adc for a microcontroller family. These code *is not tied to any project and on the contrary, this code is designed and developed individually to be used in any project*. So, I created a repository for each one and have them under version control with hg.

But recently I decided to start a project called **"Project A"** which uses the *ADC* and the *UART*. I create the "Project A" folder, create a main.c file, and finally create a repository in the "Project A" folder, add the main.c file, and commit it.

My problem here is that I want to somehow ***"add" or "link"*** the UART and ADC code to my **"Projet A"** without copy-paste the folders manually, I mean, to handle the UART and ADC code as sub-projects independent from the "Project A" and have hg to copy the most recent version for UART and ADC to the "main" project. Then if a change is needed in UART code for example, then the change is made in the UART code, commit the change to the UART project and just "update" it to the last version whithin all projects that have UART code added or linked.

I have read:

[Mercurial - Add project which is not within repository folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528112/mercurial-add-project-which-is-not-within-repository-folder)

[Do all files have to be in the 'repository folder' when using Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798696/do-all-files-have-to-be-in-the-repository-folder-when-using-mercurial?lq=1)

http://hginit.com/index.html

[Mercurial for Beginners: The Definitive Practical Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170338/mercurial-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

And I can't find the answer to my question. I found a very neat and straight-to-the-point tutorial about subprojects but it didn't really help (http://tomtech999.wordpress.com/2011/12/17/getting-started-with-mercurial-subrepositories/
)

Could you give me a series of steps to follow or a link to some tutorial to accomplish this?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for specifying what you've researched before asking; it is refreshing these days.

I think you are thinking about version controlling libraries incorrectly, see if this answer fits the model you have in your mind.

It looks to me that the libraries UART, SPI, and ADC are "libraries" in the strong sense of the word: they provide a service to a calling program like ProjectA. They could also provide these same functions to ProjectB–ProjectZ without change.

If this is so, then maintaining the libraries in a separate repository is the Right Thing To Do. If the UART changes its registers or I find a bug in the UART library, I'd want my change reflected through all users of the UART library, and the way to do that is to have a single, definitive repository for the UART library. That repository should produce a UART.a or UART.so or UART.dll as is appropriate for your system. The library will become part of ProjectA at link time. The alternative would be to have separate un-associated copies of the UART code in multiple project repositories which is an invitation to error.

I won't tell you that library generation and linking with ProjectA is nearly as easy as having all the code in one repo, but that's a limitation of `make` and friends across multiple directories (a deficiency that is very well known). Your separation of repositories does seem to make sense from a DVCS perspective though.

Comment: This is correct, nevertheless, I need a copy of the code in the main project and not just to link the .a lib file at link time. This because there might be sometimes I would need to add or remove code from the UART or SPI or ADC in order to keep improving them and sometimes at debugging may be necessary to dive in to these libraries code. So the idea is to be able to make a copy of the libraries' code in the main project and not just link the precompiled .a file.

Comment: For example in synergy when a project is created, the code for all the "support" functionality or "libraries" that provide all this common functionality is "copied" to the main project and when a working area is created then all the code is available for editing locally. If there is a bug fix of some change that needs to be done in any library then the lib "owner" makes the change, does a baseline of the library, then it is just updated in the main project to the last version.

Comment: If by "synergy" you mean IBM® Rational® Synergy Software Configuration Management, then you've got dueling SCMs and will find it very difficult to keep them consistent. And if Synergy is anything like ClearCase, may god have mercy on your soul.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I meant IBM® Rational® Synergy

Answer (score 0):

Like msw, I love that you explain what you've already read! I suggest reading

- [Mercurial Kick Start - Subrepositories](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/) — a guide a collegue of mine wrote about subrepositories.
- [Strongly cupled subrepositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616079/adapting-svnexternals-usage-for-move-to-mercurial/8637556#8637556) — an answer I wrote where I try to explain some problems you can run into with strongly coupled sub-components. I don't know what build tools you have in your world, but if possible, you should use one to manage the dependencies between the components.
- [Keeping subrepo in sync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7318280/110204) — another answer about keeping subrepos in sync on the server side.
- [Mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) and `hg help subrepos`.